# "Boolean cannot be returned by findById()" Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to write tests for an university project and I get the following error.

```
Boolean cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

This is my test:

```
@Test
    void getStatusTest1() {
        p1.setActive(true);
        when(pollService.getStatus(1L)).thenReturn(true);
        assertTrue(pollService.getStatus(p1.getId()));

    }
```

And this the service method I am testing:

```
public boolean getStatus(long id) {
        Poll poll = pollRepository
                .findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException((
                        "Poll with id " + id + "does not exist"
                )));

        return poll.isActive();
    }
```

Now as you can see the method I am testing does not return an Optional but a boolean and I don't see why I get that error. `findById()` does indeed return Optional, but why does that affect my the return type of the method?

Comment: Could the error be the `orElseThrow`, as it can only be called on objects?

Comment: @TK36 I am using the `orElseThrow` plenty in other tests and I haven't ran into any issues so far.

Comment: Perhaps you should mock this call in repository: `when(mockRepo.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(p1));`

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error message, the problem is due to the mocked result of the `findById()` method. It is not in the code you posted, but presumably is returning a boolean, rather than an `Optional<Poll>` which is what the signature of that method requires.

You should return an `Optional.of(p1)` instead:

```
when(pollRepository.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(p1));
```